# Is it possible to use Facebook search in my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a Facebook app.
I wonder if I can use the original Facebook search engine in my app via their REST API. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search over all **public** objects in the social graph with

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post

`q` is query and `type` is object

Check the API docs (look for searching)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed it :)